# Seeding profile pictures stored in S3 from Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, seeding, faker

I'm working on a Rails application and I have a has_one_attached profile picture for active storage in S3 and I would like to seed data from Faker for their avatar images when I seed my users. 
Here is the seed code:

```
20.times do
  Student.create(
      first_name: Faker::Name.first_name, 
      last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
      phone_number: Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone,
      school_id: School.first.id,
      vehicle_make_model: Faker::Vehicle.make_and_model,
      vehicle_year: Faker::Vehicle.year,
      vehicle_color: Faker::Vehicle.color,
      email_address: Faker::Internet.email,
      password: "password", 
      email: Faker::Internet.email,
      profile_picture: Faker::Avatar.image
  ).save
end
```

Here is the model for the User aka Student(this is set up correctly and works when uploading images through the site):

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  belongs_to :school, optional: true
  has_many :offers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :cars
  has_one_attached :profile_picture
end
```

I've seeded the rest of the data before and it works fine but once I integrated S3 and tried to seed with this data it no longer works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#seed_file
require 'open-uri'

def image_fetcher
    open(Faker::Avatar.image)
    rescue
    open("https://robohash.org/sitsequiquia.png?size=300x300&set=set1")
end

20.times do |n|
  s = Student.create(
     ...
     #remove profile_picture from here
  )

  s.profile_picture.attach({
     io: image_fetcher,
     filename: "#{n}_faker_image.jpg"
  })
end
```

#### UPDATE:

```
require 'faker'
require 'open-uri'

def image_fetcher
  URI.open(Faker::Avatar.image)
  rescue
  URI.open("https://robohash.org/sitsequiquia.png?size=300x300&set=set1")
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately when calling open uri I'm getting a 500 error code, specifically

Comment: OpenURI::HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @RoccoDaigler Alright, Updated my post. The reason of 500 is some of `Faker.image` url is not valid and was throwing errors. Make sure everything exactly i posted it. Also, `.save` removed, since it doesnt create directly.

Comment: I tried this exact same code and got this error: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://robohash.org/sitsequiquia.png?size=300x300&set=set1 @7urkm3n

Comment: @EltonSantos i dnt know how u have done it. But problem looks like filename: “#{n}_faker….”

Comment: @7urkm3n I did exactly the same as this code, I didn't change anything. And now, I removed the filename: “#{n}_faker... and it still gives the same error

Comment: Can you help me please? More than 1 week that I try it and nothing :/